# cv2.LUT throws an error when performing gamma correction - Assertion failed

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I wrote some code to perform gamma adjustment on an image.  To do that, I'm creating a LUT to perform gamma correction in an image.  I am receiving the following error when calling `cv2.LUT`:

> error: OpenCV(4.4.0)
> C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-52oirelq\opencv\modules\core\src\lut.cpp:368:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) (lutcn == cn || lutcn == 1) &&
> _lut.total() == 256 && _lut.isContinuous() && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_8S) in function 'cv::LUT'

The code I wrote is shown below which is a function for performing gamma correction:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
    # build a lookup table mapping the pixel values [0, 255] to
    # their adjusted gamma values
    invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
    table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
        for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")
    # apply gamma correction using the lookup table
    return cv2.LUT(image, table)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which line of your code is throwing the error? Include the full traceback if possible.

Comment: Did you look at the [apply-opencv-look-up-table-lut-to-an-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169247/apply-opencv-look-up-table-lut-to-an-image)?

Comment: i got the erorr at the return cv2.LUT(image,table)
at the gamma function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input image is most likely not unsigned 8-bit integer.  The error message is very telling as it expects the input image into `cv2.LUT` to be this type.  I suspect your image is floating point precision instead.  In that case, the easiest solution is to scale the values by 255 and cast to `uint8`, run the method then convert to floating point after:

```
output = adjust_gamma((255 * image).astype(np.uint8), table)
output = (output.astype(np.float)) / 255
```