# How to apply color correction curve in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to apply a static color correction curve to an incoming stream of images, similar to what you'd find in photoshop using Adjust Curves. What would be a good approach to doing this in OpenCV?

Comment: I suppose it may be implemented using a LUT (Look Up Table). One option is using the same LUT for all the color channels, other option is using a different LUT for each color channel.

Comment: You could get `ffmpeg` to apply a Photoshop Curves file (`curves.acv`) for you with `ffmpeg -i INPUT.MOV -vf curves=psfile="curves.acv" OUTPUT.MOV`

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70156640/2836621

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-adjust-image-curves/7365